# Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = x$ and $\theta: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{\theta(n)} = x$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent series and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$. Furthermore let $\theta : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ a mapping with the property that for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the fiber $\theta^{-1}(\{n\})$ is finite.
>
> Show that: $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{\theta(n)} = x$.

Solutions and hints are just as appreciated.

Comment: If you show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \theta(n)=\infty$, you are done (Can you see why?). The finite fiber condition will be useful to show this. The key is that $\theta^{-1}(\{n|n\leq N\})$ is finite for all $N$.

Comment: Problems like this make the notion "almost all" so convenient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that $|x_{n}-x|<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$ for some large $N$. Since $\theta^{-1}({n})$ is finite for all $n$ then for sufficiently large $m_{0}$ we can guarantee that $\theta(m)\ge N$ for all $m\ge m_{0}$. So $|x_{\theta(m)}-x|<\epsilon$ for all $m\ge m_{0}$.

More explicitly, let $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \lt N \}$. Then $\theta^{-1}(S)$ is finite (since it can be expressed as a finite union of finite fibers) and has a maximum element $n_0$. Then if $n \geq n_0 + 1$, $\theta(n) \not\in S$ and hence $\theta(n) \geq N$. If we put $m_0 = n_0 + 1$, the result follows as above.